# Llamar el resultado de una función dentro de otra

Tags: python, python-3.x

necesito llamar el resultado de una función dentro de otra que se esta definiendo

```
def palabra_u(ahorcado2):
    pal = open(ahorcado2, "r")
    lista_pal = list(pal)
    print(lista_pal)
    palabra = ""

    pal.close()
    palabra = random.choice(lista_pal)
```

esta es la primera funcion la cual se ejecunta desde un main

```
lista="palabras.txt"
palabra_u(lista)
```

quiero llamar esa funcion dentro de esta:

```
def letra_usuario(ahorcado):
    ahorcado= input("ingrese letra")

    for i in palabra :#donde quiero que  este el resultado de la función palabra_u para poder ejecutar el codigo:
        if i in letra:
            print(i, end="")
        else:
            print("_ ", end="")
```

¿como podría hacerlo?

Comment: palabra es una variable local por lo que se eliminara, lo que debes hacer es retornara para ello añade `return palabra` al final de la primera función, luego en la segunda funcion tienes que invocar la funcion antes del for loop: `lista="palabras.txt"`
`palabra = palabra_u(lista)` `for i in palabra: ....`

Answer (score 1):

Parece que ese código no funcionará por varios motivos. El primero y más evidente es que la función `palabra_u()` **no retorna nada**, sólo imprime una lista con un solo elemento. Lo que lleva al segundo fallo. La variable `lista_pal` contiene una lista con todas las palabras del texto, pero **es una lista con un sólo elemento**: la totalidad del texto, por lo que `random.choice()` siempre dará como resultado todo la totalidad de las palabras del archivo de texto.

La segunda función está mejor. Respondiendo a tu pregunta, lo que podrías hacer para utilizar el resultado de la primera función es asignarla a una variable. Por ejemplo, palabra = palabra_u("/la/ruta/a/tu/archivo.txt"). Por último, en vez de `i in letra` lo adecuado sería utilizar el operador de igualdad `==`

Sin dar muchas vueltas más o menos podría quedar así:

```py
def palabra_u(ahorcado2):
        archivo = open(ahorcado2, "r")
        todas_las_palabras = archivo.read() 
        lista_pal = todas_las_palabras.split(" ") # Se crea una lista de palabras separando el texto con espacios " "
        palabra_elegida = random.choice(lista_pal) # Se elige una palabra
        archivo.close() # Se ha leído el archivo, así que se puede cerrar
        return palabra_elegida


palabra = palabra_u("/la/ruta/a/tu/archivo.txt")  # Se asigna el valor de la función a una variable.


def letra_usuario():
    letra = input("ingrese letra")
    for i in palabra:#donde quiero que  este el resultado de la función palabra_u para poder ejecutar el codigo:
        if i == letra:
            print(i, end="")
        else:
            print("_ ", end="")

letra_usuario()
```